# Duplicate Segments in TCP

Tags: tcp

While going through the [RFC793](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.txt),
I came to know that Initial Sequence Numbers should be selected in such a way 
that segment-overlapping is prevented.

Could somebody explain how a duplicate segment would have affected the TCP had overlapping occurred?

Comment: Which part of the RFC are you referring to?

Comment: [RFC793](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) page 23.

Comment: Could you please quote it?  I could not find it on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Different operating system has different behavior. See section 4.3.2 of http://insecure.org/stf/secnet_ids/secnet_ids.html

I copied that table here:

```
Operating System    Overlap Behavior
Windows NT 4.0  Always Favors Old Data
4.4BSD  Favors New Data for Forward Overlap
Linux Favors New Data for Forward Overlap
Solaris 2.6 Always Favors Old Data
HP-UX 9.01  Favors New Data for Forward Overlap
Irix 5.3    Favors New Data for Forward Overlap
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not occurs. The sequence numbers are selected in `a way that segment-overlapping is prevented`

**Update**

The initial sequence number *preferably* is a random number. After this each segment is assigned a sequence number that is equal to sum of its offset from the beginning of the data stream and initial sequence number. Thus, even if some implementation decides to resend some segment or even split it into multiply segments, then nothing dangerous happens - the segment has it's 'address' in the stream if we consider a stream as a memory space

**Update**

Taking to account the edit of your question. The duplicate of segment's actually does occur. This happens when, for example, a receiver detects that it missed some segment. Then it requests the sender to resend that segment by sending reject. But then the missing, initially sent, segment arrives. After this the second segment that was resent arrives. Then a receiver either just drops already received segment or overwrites the data in its buffers with most recent version. In any case the stack will not inform in any way the upper layers that some data arrived if it misses some segment before this data.

Comment: Thank You for the time..
Please note that question has been edited since I found the first version a bit vague...